# How does one obtain the Jordan normal form of a matrix $A$ by studying $XI-A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules, jordan-normal-form

In our lecture notes, there's the following example problem.

> Find a Jordan normal form matrix that is similar to the following. $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & -1 & 0 & -1\\1 & 1 & 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$$

The solution begins by demonstrating that the matrix $XI-A$ is equivalent to a matrix of the form

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -(X-1) & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & (X-2)(X-1)^2\end{bmatrix}$$

From here, the notes immediately deduce that the Jordan normal form of $A$ is $$J=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

I'm struggling to understand this final step - how do we get from $B$ to $J$? I get that $J$ consists of three elementary Jordan matrices, but how are these matrices actually found?

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere. If $A$ is equiavalent to $B$ (which is  a diagonal matrix), then Jordan form of $A$ must be diagonal, too. In fact, in this case, $B\big|_{X=0}$ is **the** Jordan form of $A$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, I've just triple-checked that everything is written down correctly, so if there's a typo, it's not my fault.

Comment: Well, maybe they use some weird definition of "equivalent"?.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, two matrices $U$ and $V$ are equivalent, according to the notes, if there exist invertible matrices $G$ and $H$ such that $GUH=V.$ Note however that we're not claiming that $A$ and $B$ are equivalent, but rather that $XI-A$ and $B$ are equivalent.

Comment: My bad, I confused equivalence of matrices and similarity of matrices.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, ahh no worries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method used in the lecture notes is based $\def\KX{K[X]}$on the [structure theorem for finitely generated $\KX$-modules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modules_over_a_pid#Invariant_factor_decomposition) (more generally f.g. modules over a [PID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain)) rather than on purely linear algebraic considerations. What the given computation shows is that the $\KX$-module, defined by having $X$ act on $K^4$ by the matrix$~A$, is isomorphic to $\KX/\langle1\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle1\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle X-1\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle(X-2)(X-1)^2\rangle$ (the first two summands are trivial and can be omitted). The final factor can be further decomposed as $\KX/\langle(X-2)(X-1)^2\rangle\cong\KX/\langle X-2\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle(X-1)^2\rangle$  because of a theorem for which I am still wondering if it has a name in English (in French it is the [lemme des noyaux](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemme_des_noyaux), it is [related to the Chinese remainder theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/275186/18880), but not the same as it is about modules rather than rings).

So our $\KX$-module is isomorphic to $\KX/\langle X-1\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle(X-1)^2\rangle\oplus\KX/\langle X-2\rangle$, where I have moved to the front the two factors that contain eigenvectors for the eigenvalue$~1$. The outermost summands are of dimension$~1$, and $X$ acts as a scalar $1$ respectively $2$ on each of them; in the middle factor of dimension$~2$, the action of $X$ has eigenvalue$~1$ but is not diagonalisable: it is a Jordan block of size$~2$. So this is how one gets two Jordan blocks of sizes $1,2$ for $\lambda=1$ and a single Jordan block of size$~1$ for $\lambda=2$.

I'll add a word about the initial computation leading to the diagonal form. The algorithm applied is that of computing the [Smith normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of the matrix $XI-A$ over $\KX$ (which is a PID), using row and column operations with scalars in $\KX$ to arrive at a diagonal form in which successive diagonal entries each divide the next one. I am not sure whether your lecture notes explain why one should start with $XI-A$, and why the result describes a cyclic decomposition of the $\KX$-module defined by$~A$, so here it is. Intermediate matrices describe a presentation of a $\KX$-module as quotient of the free module $\KX^n$, where $n$ is the number of rows, by the sub-module $N$ generated by the columns of the matrix. During the algorithm, column operations correspond to changing to different generators of $N$, while row operations correspond to choosing a different basis of $\KX^n$ than the standard one, and changing coordinates (of the generators of$~N$) to the new basis. At the end of the transformation one arrives at a situation in which all generators of$~N$ are (polynomial) multiples of the basis of $\KX^n$ used, whence the diagonal form, and this describes the module as a direct sum of cyclic sub-modules.

So why does $XI-A$ describe the $\KX$-module$~M$ defined on $K^n$ by the action of$~A$? Because the standard basis $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ of $K^n$ is certainly a set of generators for$~M$ (probably quite redundant) so we have a surjective morphism $f:\KX^n\to M$, and column$~j$ of $XI-A$ describes $Xe_j-\sum_i A_{i,j}e_i\in\KX^n$ which element, given that $X$ acts on $M$ as $A$, is in the kernel $N$ of $f$ by definition; it is not hard to see that these elements generate all of$~N$, so that they give a complete presentation of$~M$.

Whether this method is a very practical manner to find a Jordan normal form is questionable; in my experience performing the Smith normal form algorithm over $\KX$ is extremely tedious an error prone by hand. However, apart from the theoretical importance, it is certainly an algorithm, while I think methods of finding the Jordan normal form by linear algebra only tend to be hard to describe as a complete algorithm (in practice many shortcuts are possible, but a complete method covering all possibilities is long to describe). I've tried to describe a linear algebraic algorithm (as well as the one above) for the somewhat coarser Rational Canonical (or Frobenius Normal) Form in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407639/18880).

Comment: Thanks for this. I just reread this answer four years later (how time flies!). Can you tell me if this is correct? Given $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$, we get a corresponding collection of matrices $\Phi(P)$ by assigning to each root of $P$ an appropriate Jordan matrix, choosing an order on the roots, and then stacking them into a square matrix. We can also go the other way; given a complex matrix $A$, we can form the matrix $X-A$ and then compute the determinant; lets call the result $\Psi(A) := \mathrm{det}(X-A)$. The important observation is that $\mathrm{JNF}(A) = \Phi(\Psi(A))$, where...

Comment: $\mathrm{JNF}(A)$ is the set of Jordan normal forms of $A$. Is this right? If so, I might write it up as an answer.

Comment: No that cannot work. If I understand you correctly $\Psi(A)$ is just the characteristic polynomial of $A$; from this information alone the Jordan normal form cannot be deduced. Nor can it be in a non contrived way from any other polynomial whose roots are eigenvalues of $A$, simply because there are too many different possible Jordan normal forms. For instance there are 11 different Jordan normal forms of $6\times6$ nilpotent (all eigenvalues $0$) matrices.

Comment: How does one find invertible matrix $T$ such that $A = TJT^{-1}$ using this method? Or does that have to be found by other means?

Answer (score 3):

$A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda_1=2$ of multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda_2=1$ of multiplicty $3$. Apparently, the Jordan block corresponding to $2$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix and thus uniteresting for us.

Next, we study $\text{rank} (A-I)$. It's easy to check that the rank is equal to $2$, so we conclude that $A$ has $4-2=2$ linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $1$. It yields the structure of Jordan blocks: one is $1\times 1$ matrix and the other one is a $2\times 2$ (other possibilities are ruled out: three $1\times 1$ matrices would require 3 eigenvectors and one $3\times 3$ would require only one eigenvector). Thus, we conclude that the Jordan form is indeed $$J=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 2\end{bmatrix}.$$

In more general case, the algorithm is a little bit more complex: you study eigenvalues, then eigenvectors, and then generalized eigenvectors.

Comment: So basically, since $\mathrm{rank}(A)-\mathrm{rank}(A-\lambda I) = 4-2=2$ for $\lambda=1,$ thus $J$ must have precisely two elementary Jordan elementary matrices corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$?? Is this a general principle?

Comment: Yes, the number of eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvalue is equal to the number of Jordan cells corresponding to that eigenvalue.

Comment: This is a correct computation, but the method is fundamentally different than the one used in the text cited.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Indeed it is; and, as an additional benefit, it is intuitive and relies only on the idea behind Jordan decomposition.

Comment: This method is certainly simpler, at least for hand computation, in most concrete cases (as I indicate in my answer). But giving a complete algorithm which in particular will in all cases provide a Jordan basis as well is surprisingly difficult.