# Is there a fast method to calculate the non-singular matrix for the rational canonical form?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

I want to take this question as an example:

[Rational canonical form(Frobenius normal form) of the matrix $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764150/rational-canonical-form-of-the-matrix-a)

The matrix looks like:

$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 2 \\
-2 & -1 & -4 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
$$

The rational canonical form (Frobenius normal form) is:

$$
R=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

It is said that the two will be similar. That is, $A=S^{-1}RS$ for some non-singular $S$. My questions are (the first one is kind of silly but it really confused me):

1. The other way around. If I can find some matrix $S$ such that $A=S^{-1}RS$, can I guarantee that $S$ is invertible?
2. (Main question) How do I find a non-singular matrix $S$ to make the equation $A=S^{-1}RS$ hold.

Currently, I assume $S$ takes the form

$$
S=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]
$$

Then do $A=S^{-1}RS\Rightarrow SA=RS$, that is,

$$
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 2 \\
-2 & -1 & -4 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -2 & 0 \\
1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]
$$

But I cannot solve $S$ out......

Then, the question 2 becomes how to find the $
S=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{array}\right]
$.

**And also, I think there might be some method using the idea of decompositions can solve this much faster, I just cannot figure it out.**

It would be helpful if anyone has some hint on the problem. Thank you all very much.

Comment: For googling purposes, "Frobenius normal form" is apparently synonymous with "rational canonical form". Searching in MSE under that name instead brings up this answer, which gives some basic ideas for algorithms: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/407639/137524

Comment: Thank you very much. About the synonymous, I am aware of that, I will update it to the question. The link really helps. But I still couldn't figure it out.